# How to get the peak dynamicly allocated memory usage of a C/C++ program in Linux system

Tags: c, memory-management, heap-memory, glibc

I would like to know the peak dynamicly allocated memory usage (have already canceled the released memory usage) after running a `C/C++` program.

**1 (Initial question):**

Given a C/C++ program `a.out`. Can any tool report the peak dynamically allocated memory usage in a way like:

```
>$ peak-memory ./a.out  
Peak dynamically allocated memory size: 12345678 Bytes
```

**2 (Alternative question):**

Can I insert a snippit code in the source program such that every time it is executed, it will report the current heap memory usage where I want. This looks like:

```
int main(){
    int *a = (int*) malloc(12);
    // some code...
    print_heap_usage();
    // other code...
}
```

**My research:**

I know I can use a wrapper function such as `my_malloc` and `my_free` that track the allocated and released memory. But it is not a practical option for other's source code when too many lines of code need to be modified. And prohibitively, this wrapper function can't handle the situation when `new` and `delete` are used.

There is one related question [Get peak amount of memory used by a C program](http://Get%20peak%20amount%20of%20memory%20used%20by%20a%20C%20program). But it's only about Windows system and doesn't specifically care about heap memory usage. Some answers indicated the using of `getrusage`. However, I googled and found it clearly can't tell the heap usage.

Comment: Are you sure you need exactly the malloc heap? What if the program allocates memory using `mmap` as well? Would it be useful to know just the peak resident set size?

Comment: Yes, just malloc/free heap and new/delete heap. I don't consider ```mmap``` . Just curious, what difference of the answer if I consider ```mmap```.

Comment: One question is asking about only memory allocated via `malloc/new`, and the other is asking about all sources of dynamic allocation. The reason is that "max resident set size" is a complete measurement of the process' impact on the system (and max RSS - shared size is useful for understanding scalability). These are statistics gathered about all processes.

Comment: @Useless I am doing memory profiling of my program. I want to know peak heap memory usage so I can know if it is runnable or not for a computer. I just google ```RSS```, and have a doubt if my computer has a maximum 4GB RAM, and my program totally malloced  4.5GB RAM(I won't use ```mmap``` thing), will there be some swap space to use to make the program run, or it just fail on malloc and exit.

Comment: If you want to know whether it will run on a computer, surely you need to know the total memory used?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Either

[Statistics for Memory Allocation with malloc](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/mallinfo.3.html)

or

[malloc_stats](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/malloc_stats.3.html)

**Note**: check the CONFORMING TO sections.

Another gimmick (in terminal):

- `cat /proc/meminfo`
- `free` (from procps package, uses /proc/meminfo, see https://gitlab.com/procps-ng/procps/-/blob/master/proc/sysinfo.c line 698 in function `meminfo`)